# I have an unknown gap/space between my heading and navigation divs. I've tried looking up answers but nothing seems to offer a fix

Tags: html, css, navigation, containers, margin

I have tried setting the margin-bottom of my heading div to 0 and margin-top to 0 for my navigation div. Nothing seems to work.

When I set my margin-bottom on my navigation div i can surely add space between my navigation and container div no problem.

I just seem to have no control over the movement of my navigation div with respect to my heading.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:link {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.heading {
  height: 100px;
  background: beige;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20pt;
  text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em white;
  font-family: "cookie";
}

.navigation {
  height: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: lightblue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 600px;
  background: beige;
  width: 666px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content-heading {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-heading {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 334px;
  background: lightgreen;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidebar-content {
  width: 334px;
  min-height: 550px;
  background: lightgreen;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  background: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.heading-child {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.sidebar-heading-child {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.footer-child {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Cookie:regular"]
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1 class="heading-child">All I Want is Whirled Peas!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-heading"><strong>Welcome</strong></div>
      This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content
      of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section.
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-heading">
      <div class="sidebar-heading-child"><strong>Additional Info</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello
      this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content.
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footer-child">Website created by Josh &copy 2017</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a google for collapsing margins and you will understand why the answer below is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default `h1` & `ul` tags take some `margin` from top & bottom, just set it to `margin:0`. check below snippet for this.

```js
 WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Cookie:regular"]
      }
    });
```

```css
 *{
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 a:link {
     color: black;
 }

 a:hover {
     color: white;
 }

 ul {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0px;
     list-style-type: none;
 }

 .container {
     width: 1000px;
     background: red;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .heading {
     height: 100px;
     background: beige;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 20pt;
     text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em white;
     font-family: "cookie";
 }

 .navigation {
     height: 50px;
     width: 1000px;
     background: lightblue;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     line-height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .navigation ul li {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 40px;
 }

 .navigation ul li a {
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .content {
     min-height: 600px;
     background: beige;
     width: 666px;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding: 0 15px;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: sans-serif;
 }

 .content-heading {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     min-height: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .sidebar-heading {
     min-height: 50px;
     width: 334px;
     background: lightgreen;
     float: right;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: sans-serif;
 }

 .sidebar-content {
     width: 334px;
     min-height: 550px;
     background: lightgreen;
     float: right;
     padding: 0 15px;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .footer {
     clear: both;
     background: lightblue;
     height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     font-family: sans-serif;
 }

 .heading-child {
     line-height: 100px;
 }

 .sidebar-heading-child {
     line-height: 50px;
 }

 .footer-child {
     line-height: 50px;
 }

 h1 {
     margin: 0px;
 }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
 
<div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
        <h1 class="heading-child">All I Want is Whirled Peas!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-heading"><strong>Welcome</strong></div>
        This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section. This is content of the content section.
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-heading">
        <div class="sidebar-heading-child"><strong>Additional Info</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content. Hello this is sidebar content.
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footer-child">Website created by Josh &copy 2017</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses! I solved the problem. I tried setting the h1 {margin:0;} as advised and it didn't work but it got me thinking about looking at hidden/default margins. I set my ul {margin:0;} and that worked. Though I'm still a little confused as to why that worked? I guess I don't fully understand unordered lists.